# Return tuple with smallest y value from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, min

I am trying to return a tuple the smallest second index value (y value) from a list of tuples. If there are two tuples with the lowest y value, then select the tuple with the largest x value (i.e first index).

For example, suppose I have the tuple:

```
x = [(2, 3), (4, 3), (6, 9)]
```

The the value returned should be `(4, 3)`. `(2, 3)` is a candidate, as `x[0][1]` is `3` (same as `x[1][1]`), however, `x[0][0]` is smaller than `x[1][0]`.

So far I have tried:

```
start_point = min(x, key = lambda t: t[1])
```

However, this only checks the second index, and does not compare two tuples first index if their second index's are equivalent.

Comment: You could try something like: `min(x, key=lambda t: [t[1], -t[0]])`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Include the `x` value in a tuple returned from the key; this second element in the key will be then used when there is a tie for the `y` value. To inverse the comparison (from smallest to largest), just negate that value:

```
min(x, key=lambda t: (t[1], -t[0]))
```

After all, `-4` is smaller than `-2`.

Demo:

```
>>> x = [(2, 3), (4, 3), (6, 9)]
>>> min(x, key=lambda t: (t[1], -t[0]))
(4, 3)
```

Comment: @ByteCommander: because in a tie the *larger* `x` value should be selected, not the smaller.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. And only one line required!